# MySQL Fields alternative to 'is_active', 'is_banned' flags?

Tags: php, mysql

I've encountered a table has ~20 fields of 'is_X' (is_active, is_banned, is_allowed_to_view_something and so on) and it seems just plain wrong.

I am familiar with the bitwise method by storing an INT in one field and then breaking it to bits and using it as flags but is there any other way to store a lot of information (most of it is yes/no) in a MySQL table without cluttering the table with tons of fields?

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to use statuses column. instead of single column for every status. It can be done by serializing object with user's statuses or just simply saving JSON.

Benefits:

- easy to manage
- your table gets smaller

Comment: Yeah but that will make it hard to filter/search through one specific column, for example if i want to get all the 'is_banned' and 'is_admin' together...isn't it?

Comment: There are few ways to search/filter by this field depanding on what you need.
1) If you need to get banned user or admins you can just use LIKE in your  query
2) If you want to check if user has status you jus simply check if it exist in column

Comment: For point 1) Problem is if you have too many rows then there may be performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Bit columns are usefull because easy to use.

An other way could be a right table (I assume you are working on a user table)

```
user <=> user_has_right <=> right
```

Table `right` is supposed to store multiple rows which are `active`, `banned`, etc ...

Basically, `user_has_right` has 2 foreign keys : `fk_id_user` and `fk_id_right`.
If an entry exist, then the user has the right to ...

Example :
Suppose you want all active users.
Suppose `id_right` for active users is 1.

```
SELECT * FROM user u
INNER JOIN user_has_right uhr ON uhr.fk_id_user = u.id_user
INNER JOIN rights r ON r.id_right = uhr.fk_id_rights
WHERE r.id_right = 1;
```

Comment: Thought about joins but once you have lots of 'is_X' fields JOINing lots of table wont do the affect...maybe just for rights/roles

Comment: I agree there is cons to this solution that was I was starting by saying bit columns where easy to use =)

Answer (score 0):

*MySQL* does have a [BIT type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html), but all the [bit functions and operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html) currently require `BIGINT` (64-bit) arguments and returns. If you can live with the cast to/from `BIGINT`, you can use any sufficiently large (for your application) integer type and use bitmasks with bitwise `or`s and `and`s to set and clear (respectively) individual bits.

Clearly, the intended semantic of each bit-position is not explicit, and so less clear than individual `is_A`, `is_B`, ... columns, but you might be able to ameliorate that somewhat with a table of set/clear bitmasks.

It depends on what you're doing, how you use the fields, etc. and (of course) on your own particular preferences, biases, etc. on where the balance lies and whether one is better than the other for a particular situation.

Also, if you Google around, and you'll find that there may be [some issues and bugs](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/) with `BIT` in older versions (around 5.0.x) of MySQL.